# How to set labels for X and Y axis in dual line chart using aChartEngine in android?

Tags: android, achartengine, linechart

Hi all I am very new to chart applications. I created dual line chart using aChartEngine for my android application. I cant set labels for y-axis in my chart.

I got chart like this.....

[image]

How can i do this can anybody help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will help you:

```
// hide the default labels
mrenderer.setYLabels(0);
// set the custom labels
mrenderer.addYTextLabel(0, "$0");
mrenderer.addYTextLabel(20000, "$20K");
...
// set the visible range
mrenderer.setYAxisMin(0);
mrenderer.setYAxisMax(140000);
```

Comment: Hey Dan i got an error like this The method addYAxisLabel(int, String) is undefined for the type XYMultipleSeriesRenderer

Comment: ya Dan i got it. Thanks man!!! but if i use like this         for(int j=0 ; j<y.length ; j++)
        {
         mrenderer.addYTextLabel(j, y[j]);
        }
        mrenderer.setYLabels(1);                                          its overlapping in 0 th position.

Comment: If you want to make it dynamically, then use the below code for(int j=0 ; j<y.length ; j++)
        {
          mrenderer.addYTextLabel(y1[j], y[j]);
        }
        mrenderer.setYLabels(0);

Comment: it appears we needn't hide the default labels. We just wanted the default labels with two special labels. Awesome library Tx Dan!